# How to send model bind to devexpress gridview back to controller during callback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, devexpress

I would like to pass the model bind to devexpress gridview back to controller during callback but failed.

**Models**

```
public class UploadExcelError
{
    public int rowNumber { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class UploadViewModel
{
    public List<UploadExcelError> UploadExcelErrors { get; set; }
    public UploadFile UploadFile { get; set; }
}
```

**UploadErrorPartial.cshtml**

```
@using ControlTower2.Models
@model ControlTower2.Models.UploadViewModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.UploadExcelErrors != null)
    {

        @Html.DevExpress().GridView(
            settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "gridViewExcelError";
                settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "PurchaseOrder", Action = "FilteringError", xyz = Model };
                settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSort = false;
                settings.SettingsPager.Mode = GridViewPagerMode.ShowAllRecords;
                settings.Columns.Add(column => { column.FieldName = "rowNumber"; column.Caption = "Excel Row#"; });
                settings.Columns.Add(column => { column.FieldName = "errorMessage"; column.Caption = "Error Message"; });
                settings.Settings.ShowHeaderFilterButton = true;
                var headerFilterMode = GridHeaderFilterMode.List;
                foreach (GridViewDataColumn column in settings.Columns)
                    column.SettingsHeaderFilter.Mode = headerFilterMode;
            }
        ).Bind(Model.UploadExcelErrors).GetHtml()
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult FilteringError(UploadViewModel xyz)
{
    return PartialView("UploadErrorPartial", xyz);
}
```

`xyz` is null in code above.

I also tried:

```
settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "PurchaseOrder", Action = "FilteringError", xyz = Model.UploadExcelErrors };

public ActionResult FilteringError(List<UploadExcelError> xyz)
{
    UploadViewModel uploadViewModel = new UploadViewModel();
    uploadViewModel.UploadExcelErrors = xyz;
    return PartialView("UploadErrorPartial", uploadViewModel);
}
```

`xyz` is not null but count is zero. But It has show 4 rows of data on UploadErrorPartial.cshtml

I tried ViewData too:

**UPDATE** - ViewData only transfers data from controller to view, that's why this won't work.

```
if (Model.UploadExcelErrors != null)
{
    ViewData["xyz"] = Model;
    @Html.DevExpress().GridView(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "gridViewExcelError";
            settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "PurchaseOrder", Action = "FilteringError" };
            settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSort = false;
            settings.SettingsPager.Mode = GridViewPagerMode.ShowAllRecords;
            settings.Columns.Add(column => { column.FieldName = "rowNumber"; column.Caption = "Excel Row#"; });
            settings.Columns.Add(column => { column.FieldName = "errorMessage"; column.Caption = "Error Message"; });
            settings.Settings.ShowHeaderFilterButton = true;
            var headerFilterMode = GridHeaderFilterMode.List;
            foreach (GridViewDataColumn column in settings.Columns)
                column.SettingsHeaderFilter.Mode = headerFilterMode;
        }
    ).Bind(Model.UploadExcelErrors).GetHtml()
}

public ActionResult FilteringError()
{
    UploadViewModel uploadViewModel = (UploadViewModel)ViewData["xyz"];
    return PartialView("UploadErrorPartial", uploadViewModel);
}
```

`uploadViewModel` get null from `(UploadViewModel)ViewData["xyz"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I use session to store `Model.UploadExcelErrors` and it solves my problem.